# Can't change featured image when editing blog post

Tags: php, image

I'm creating a PHP and SQL blog. Among other files, I have upload_file.php and edit_post.php. Every time I edit a post, it updates all the information except for the featured image. It won't upload a new featured image. Here is upload_file.php:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

if (!empty($_FILES['post_image']['name'])) {

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["post_image"]["name"]);

$image_name = basename($_FILES["post_image"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["post_image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $file_image = "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $file_not_image = "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $file_exists = "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["post_image"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    $file_too_large = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $file_not_allowed = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $file_not_uploaded = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["post_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $file_uploaded = "The file ". basename( $_FILES["post_image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        $file_error = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

}

}

?>
```

Here is edit_post.php, minus the form:

```
<?php include("session_start.php")?>

<?php include("upload_file.php")?>

<?php include("links.php"); ?>

<?php include("navigation.php"); ?> 

<?php

if($_GET['id'] != ""){

$post_id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id='$post_id' AND user_name='$user_name'";

$post = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

}

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT post_category FROM posts WHERE user_name='$user_name'";

$cat = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

?>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$post_title = isset($_POST['post_title']) ? $_POST['post_title'] : null;
$post_content = isset($_POST['post_content']) ? $_POST['post_content'] : null;
if($_POST['new_category']==""){
$post_category = ($_POST['choose_category']);
}else{
$post_category = ($_POST['new_category']);
}
$post_date = isset($_POST['post_date']) ? $_POST['post_date'] : null;

if (isset($image_name)){
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET post_title='$post_title', post_content='$post_content', post_category='$post_category', post_date='$post_date', post_image='$image_name' WHERE post_id='$post_id' AND user_name='$user_name'";
}else{
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET post_title='$post_title', post_content='$post_content', post_category='$post_category', post_date='$post_date' WHERE post_id='$post_id' AND user_name='$user_name'";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

header('Location: index.php');

}

?>

<?php include "footer.php";?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the reason this wasn't working is because I forgot to put enctype="multipart/form-data" on my form!